# clearing a grid with multhithreading

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, loops

I am trying to clear a (game) grid, but whenever I multithread it, the time it takes to clear the grid increases with 3 seconds.
To my own logic this should not be the case since each Y value of the array hold a lot of X values (the X values store a class) which then should iterate through a so called `objects` property and perform `objects.clear()` on it, which also iterates through every element.

My code:

```
    const int NUM_OF_AVAIL_THREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() * 2;
    ThreadPool* pool = new ThreadPool(NUM_OF_AVAIL_THREADS);
    vector<future<void>> threads;

    void Terrain::clear_grid()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < tiles.size(); y++)
        {
            threads.push_back(pool->enqueue([&]()
                {
                    array<TerrainTile, terrain_width>& h = tiles.at(y);
                    for (int x = 0; x < h.size(); x++)
                    {
                        h.at(x).objects.clear();
                    }
                }));
        }
        pool->wait_and_clear_threads(threads);
    }
```

TerrainTile looks like this:

```
    class TerrainTile
    {
    public:
        //TerrainTile *up, *down, *left, *right;
        vector<TerrainTile*> exits;
        bool visited = false;
        size_t position_x;
        size_t position_y;
        TileType tile_type;
        vector<TerrainTile*> neighbors;

        vector<MovingAsset*> objects;
        vector<Tank*> tanks;
        vector<MovingAsset*> beams;
        vector<MovingAsset*> get_collidable_assets();
        void add_collidable_assets(MovingAsset* asset);
        void add_neighbor(TerrainTile* neighbor);
    };
```

How the tiles array looks like:

```
static constexpr size_t terrain_width = 80;
static constexpr size_t terrain_height = 45;
std::array<std::array<TerrainTile, terrain_width>, terrain_height> tiles;
```

am I missing out on something crucial here, or does the cost of creating a thread simply outweigh the time it takes to iterate through the arrays?

***EDIT: THIS IS THE THREADPOOL***

```
#pragma once

namespace Tmpl8
{

    class ThreadPool; //Forward declare

    class Worker;

    class Worker
    {
    public:
        //Instantiate the worker class by passing and storing the threadpool as a reference
        Worker(ThreadPool& s) : pool(s) {}

        inline void operator()();

    private:
        ThreadPool& pool;
    };

    class ThreadPool
    {
    public:
        ThreadPool(size_t numThreads) : stop(false)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i)
                workers.push_back(std::thread(Worker(*this)));
        }

        ~ThreadPool()
        {
            stop = true; // stop all threads
            condition.notify_all();

            for (auto& thread : workers)
                thread.join();
        }

        void wait_and_clear_threads(vector<future<void>>& threads)
        {
            for (future<void>& t : threads)
            {
                t.wait();
            }
            threads.clear();
        }

        template <class T>
        auto enqueue(T task) -> std::future<decltype(task())>
        {
            //Wrap the function in a packaged_task so we can return a future object
            auto wrapper = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task())()>>(std::move(task));

            //Scope to restrict critical section
            {
                //lock our queue and add the given task to it
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);

                tasks.push_back([=]
                    {
                        (*wrapper)();
                    });
            }

            //Wake up a thread to start this task
            condition.notify_one();

            return wrapper->get_future();
        }

    private:
        friend class Worker; //Gives access to the private variables of this class

        std::vector<std::thread> workers;
        std::deque<std::function<void()>> tasks;

        std::condition_variable condition; //Wakes up a thread when work is available

        std::mutex queue_mutex; //Lock for our queue
        bool stop = false;
    };

    inline void Worker::operator()()
    {
        std::function<void()> task;
        while (true)
        {
            //Scope to restrict critical section
            //This is important because we don't want to hold the lock while executing the task,
            //because that would make it so only one task can be run simultaneously (aka sequantial)
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(pool.queue_mutex);

                //Wait until some work is ready or we are stopping the threadpool
                //Because of spurious wakeups we need to check if there is actually a task available or we are stopping
                pool.condition.wait(locker, [=] { return pool.stop || !pool.tasks.empty(); });

                if (pool.stop) break;

                task = pool.tasks.front();
                pool.tasks.pop_front();
            }

            task();
        }
    }

} // namespace Tmpl8
```

Comment: What does ```clear()``` do? Does it free some memory?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik objects is a vector. clear removes the elements. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/

Comment: How is your grid aligned in memory (i.e. what does tiles look like)? Also, how big is your y? If it's reasonably big, it might be outnumbering the available threads on your machine; thus thread creation slows you down and the threads do still have to wait for each other

Comment: @RawkFist I made an edit to show you how tiles looks like.

Comment: Where are the MovingAssets created that you store in objects? If they are close to one another in memory this might be a caching problem

Comment: 3 seconds to clear the grid only once (ie. 1 iteration)? It cannot be due to the clear. Thus, It should be due to the `threads.push_back(pool->enqueue` part. The thing is there is no information about what is `pool` or `threads`. Can you provide this. Btw, if you create 45 thread, then it can be a bit slow but, still, 3 seconds is very long for that. I think something else that is not provided in your question is responsible for the overhead.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I can provide the threadpool. A moment please

Comment: Ok, the naming of future vector as ```threads``` can be misleading. Then it must be overhead of future vs overhead of just a function and clear ovehead.

Comment: Thank you code the code. Can you clarify the other point: the time measured (eg. 1 iteration VS multiple).

Comment: How long does it take without threads? 0 seconds? Why are you even multithreading this? Also your `[&]` is wrong. You capture a reference to `y`, which means as the loop progresses the value of `y` in each thread changes. Also access to tiles and y will cause congestion.